# Is it possible to use Webpack to bundle Node libraries so resulting code would work with execjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

My server side is rails and I'm trying to do isomorphic rendering with react and relay. The only way I found is using the npm module isomorphic-relay. Apparently it is using node-fetch which in turn is using the 'http' library. Is it possible to use webpack (or some other tool) to create a single bundle including all the code and then run it with execjs (with Node as the engine)? When I use Node as the target webpack leaves 'http' as an external require, assuming Node will load it, so execjs can't run it...

Details:

My source file is the single line

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');
```

With webpack config:

```
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'webpack'),
    publicPath: '/webpack/',

    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
```

The resulting bundle includes various requires like this:

```
/* 3 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

        module.exports = require("url");

/***/ },
/* 4 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

        module.exports = require("http");

/***/ },
/* 5 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

        module.exports = require("https");

/***/ },
```

It works ok with Node (doing nothing obviously) but when execjs tries to execute it (with node as the engine) it gets the error:

```
Encountered error: "TypeError: require is not a function"
```

If I change the webpack config as follows:

```
//  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'webpack'),
    publicPath: '/webpack/',

    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
//    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
```

The resulting code does run with execjs but then I get the following error:

```
Encountered error: "ReferenceError: self is not defined"
```

After spending a lot of time around it I think it is because it includes the wrong version of 'fetch' assuming it is aimed for the browser and not for the backend. In package.json of isomorphic-fetch there is

```
  "browser": "fetch-npm-browserify.js",
```

and also:

```
  "main": "fetch-npm-node.js",
```

It seems like fetch-npm-browserify.js is causing the 'self' problem, while fetch-npm-node.js would try to require all those node libraries like url, http, etc and would therefore not work with execjs.

I guess I need some way to use node as a target, but somehow make webpack include all those node libraries (http, etc) in the bundle itself so execjs can execute it.

Comment: Have you tried using [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify)?

Comment: @bolav the problem is that this is server-side code, and not browser code. When I use browserify I get an error saying 'self' is not defined. When I drilled into the bundle I saw that isomorphic-relay is requiring isomorphic-fetch, which in turn requires the wrong version of fetch when targeted for the browser. When I use webpack it does include the server library, node-fetch, but then I get the issue above...

Comment: If you include some code, where you demonstrate the problem, maybe it's easier to help you.

Comment: @bolav not sure what code to include. Even a single line that just requires isomorphic-relay (or isomorphic-fetch) doesn't work unless I use node itself (rather than node through execjs).

Comment: It would be much more useful, and easier for me to help you if you include what you have tried, and what the result was, with complete reusable code. Now I need to figure out a test case, run it, see what the error was, and then guess if that is the same problem as you are having. Even though you think it's easy to reproduce this problem, it helps if you include information.

Comment: @bolav sorry, adding the details to the question

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. `node-fetch` is made by nodejs standard libraries such as `http`, `url`, `zlib`, etc, and `execjs` is not able to reach any of nodejs modules.